# trigger latching 3v relay with signal from HT12D

Tags: esp8266, decoder

I am sending a signal from an HT12E through an rf transmitter to an rf receiver then an HT12D.  This all works fine and the data signal from the HT12D is sent to a CZH-LABS D-1022A(for filling a pool).  The pulse triggers the relay on the CHZ so that works ok.
What I want to do is take the same pulse/signal from the HT12D and send it through a 3vdc regulator (it is currently at 5vdc) and then through an EC2-3TNU latching relay. 
The relay would then turn on power to an ESP12E, which would connect to the wifi and send a message to ThingSpeak that the original signal was received and the pool filling relay triggered.
The problem is that even though the signal from the HT12D reads 3vdc and it lights up an LED light when the signal is received, it doesn't trigger the latching relay.
I am attaching a schematic to show the wiring of my project.

To summarize:
The 5vdc (converted to 3vdc) signal from the HT12D will light up an LED but won't trigger a 3vdc latching relay EC2-3TNU.
I thought I may be the size of the smoothing capacitor after the center tap rectifier, but if I connect the ESP12E up to 3vdc and the activate the signal the LED still lights up but the latching relay won't engage.

I am flummoxed!  Can anyone think of why the latching relay isn't activated by the 3vdc signal?  Could it be I need a larger capacitor?  The latching relay works because if I tap it with a 3vdc lead it triggers.  This has nothing to do with code so I'm not providing any.  Although once the ESP12E is activated, connects to the wifi and uploads to ThingSpeak, the ESP is coded to turn on an output pin to activate the latching relays reset pin turning off the ESP until the next signal input.

Any suggestions to solve this problem or a work around would be greatly appreciated.
I can't create tags and one for HT12D or HT12E would really be helpful.
[image]

Comment: I think it is better to post this in electronics forums. Try posting it here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out.  Just added a transistor, diode, and resistor.[image]